# Javascript set theme for each graph

Tags: javascript, highcharts

http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-basic/sand-signika

I have several graphs in one page and they are all loaded within the same page.

I want to set theme for each graph differently but the problem is the theme that is set at first overwrites all the themes for next coming graphs. Is there any way that I can set `HighChart`'s theme locally for each graphs?

```
/**
 * Sand-Signika theme for Highcharts JS
 * @author Torstein Honsi
 */

// Load the fonts
Highcharts.createElement('link', {
   href: 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Signika:400,700',
   rel: 'stylesheet',
   type: 'text/css'
}, null, document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]);

// Add the background image to the container
Highcharts.wrap(Highcharts.Chart.prototype, 'getContainer', function (proceed) {
   proceed.call(this);
   this.container.style.background = 'url(http://www.highcharts.com/samples/graphics/sand.png)';
});


Highcharts.theme = {
   colors: ["#f45b5b", "#8085e9", "#8d4654", "#7798BF", "#aaeeee", "#ff0066", "#eeaaee",
      "#55BF3B", "#DF5353", "#7798BF", "#aaeeee"],
   chart: {
      backgroundColor: null,
      style: {
         fontFamily: "Signika, serif"
      }
   },
   title: {
      style: {
         color: 'black',
         fontSize: '16px',
         fontWeight: 'bold'
      }
   },
   subtitle: {
      style: {
         color: 'black'
      }
   },
   tooltip: {
      borderWidth: 0
   },
   legend: {
      itemStyle: {
         fontWeight: 'bold',
         fontSize: '13px'
      }
   },
   xAxis: {
      labels: {
         style: {
            color: '#6e6e70'
         }
      }
   },
   yAxis: {
      labels: {
         style: {
            color: '#6e6e70'
         }
      }
   },
   plotOptions: {
      series: {
         shadow: true
      },
      candlestick: {
         lineColor: '#404048'
      },
      map: {
         shadow: false
      }
   },

   // Highstock specific
   navigator: {
      xAxis: {
         gridLineColor: '#D0D0D8'
      }
   },
   rangeSelector: {
      buttonTheme: {
         fill: 'white',
         stroke: '#C0C0C8',
         'stroke-width': 1,
         states: {
            select: {
               fill: '#D0D0D8'
            }
         }
      }
   },
   scrollbar: {
      trackBorderColor: '#C0C0C8'
   },

   // General
   background2: '#E0E0E8'

};

// Apply the theme
Highcharts.setOptions(Highcharts.theme);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can send in the theme settings with the chart options instead of setting them globally, as in [this JSFiddle demonstration](https://jsfiddle.net/7810exbj/). The relevant code is:

```
var theme1 = {
    // Theme settings
}

var options = {
    // Chart options
}

$('#container').highcharts(Highcharts.merge(options, theme1));
```

Credit to [Moes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16006665/2732991)