# Multiple Hightchart Themes in same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Hello I want to set multiple hight chart themes in a page
I have 4 chart. I want 
chart 1 : default theme

chart 2 : sand theme

chart 3 : black theme

chart 4 : grid_light

I already tried from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15030914/highcharts-js-multiple-themes-on-same-page) question 
 but my chart themes do not change.

- code sand.js
  http://pastebin.com/66WeFqTs
- code black.js
  http://pastebin.com/4yNDamgJ
- code grid_light.js
  http://pastebin.com/TgpJutZ8

  ```
  <script>
  //Chart 1
  $(function () {
      $('#chart1').highcharts({
          title: {
              text: 'Total Kunjungan Per Bulan',
              x: -20 //center
          },
          xAxis: {
              categories: ['Januari', 'Februari', 'Maret', 'April', 'Mei', 'Juni',
                  'Juli', 'Agustus', 'September', 'Oktober', 'November', 'Desember']
          },
          yAxis: {
              title: {
                  text: 'Total Kunjungan Per Bulan'
              },
              tickInterval: 1,
              plotLines: [{
                  value: 0,
                  width: 1,
                  color: '#808080'
              }]
          },       tooltip:{
                  formatter:function(){
                      console.log(this);
                      return   this.key + ' : ' + this.y + ' Kunjungan';
                  }
              },

          series: [{
              name: '<?php echo $hasil->nama_sekolah?>',
              data: [
              <?php
              $years = date("Y");
              $data_ds = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) as hitung FROM `sekolah_kunjungan` where  kode='$hasil->kode' and tahun_kunjungan='$years' group by bulan_kunjungan");
              while ($ds=mysql_fetch_object($data_ds)) {
              echo "".$ds->hitung.",";
              }
              ?>
              ]
          }]
      });
  });
  </script>

  <script>
  //Chart 2
  $(function () {
      $('#chart2').highcharts({

          chart: {
              type: 'column'
          },
          title: {
              text: 'Jumlah Pengunjung Per Tahun'
          },
          yAxis: {
              min: 0,
              labels: {
                  format: '{value:.y:,.0f}'
              },
              title: {
                  text: 'Kunjungan / Tahun'
              },
              tickInterval: 1
          },
          tooltip: {
              headerFormat: '<table>',
              pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                  '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y} Kunjungan/Tahun</b></td></tr>',
              footerFormat: '</table>',
              shared: true,
              useHTML: true,
          },
          plotOptions: {
              column: {
                  pointPadding: 0.2,
                  borderWidth: 0
              }
          },
          series: [
          <?php 
          $data_th = mysql_query("SELECT count( id_kunjungan ) AS hitung, tahun_kunjungan FROM sekolah_kunjungan where  kode='$hasil->kode' group by tahun_kunjungan");
              while ($th=mysql_fetch_object($data_th)) {
          ?>{
              name: '<?php echo $th->tahun_kunjungan ?>',
              data: [<?php echo $th->hitung ?>]

          }, 
          <?php }?>
          ]
      });
  });

  </script>



  <script>
  //Chart 3
  $(function () {
      $('#chart3').highcharts({
          chart: {
              plotBackgroundColor: null,
              plotBorderWidth: null,
              plotShadow: false
          },
          title: {
              text: 'Jumlah Pendaftar Berdasarkan Jenis Kelamin'
          },

          tooltip: {
              pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.y}</b>'
          },
          plotOptions: {
              pie: {
                  allowPointSelect: true,
                  cursor: 'pointer',
                  dataLabels: {
                      enabled: true,
                      format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.y}',
                      style: {
                          color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                      }
                  }
              }
          },
          series: [{
              type: 'pie',
              name: 'Total',
              data: [
              <?php 
              $data_jk = mysql_query("SELECT count(id_daftar) as hitung,jenis FROM sekolah_daftar where  kode='$hasil->kode' group by jenis");
                  while ($jk=mysql_fetch_object($data_jk)) {
              ?>
                  ['<?php echo $jk->jenis?>', <?php echo $jk->hitung ?>],
              <?php } ?>

              ]
          }]
      });
  });

  </script>


  <script>
  //Chart 4
  $(function () {
      $('#chart4').highcharts({
          chart: {
              type: 'column'
          },
          title: {
              text: 'Jumlah Pendaftar Pertahun Ajaran'
          },
          yAxis: {
              min: 0,
              labels: {
                  format: '{value:.y:,.0f}'
              },
              title: {
                  text: 'Pendaftar / Tahun'
              },
              tickInterval: 1
          },
          tooltip: {
              headerFormat: '<table>',
              pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                  '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y} Pendaftar/Tahun</b></td></tr>',
              footerFormat: '</table>',
              shared: true,
              useHTML: true,
          },
          plotOptions: {
              column: {
                  pointPadding: 0.2,
                  borderWidth: 0
              }
          },
          series: [
          <?php 
          $data_th = mysql_query("SELECT count( id_daftar ) AS hitung, tahun_kunjungan FROM sekolah_daftar where  kode='$hasil->kode' group by tahun_kunjungan");
              while ($th=mysql_fetch_object($data_th)) {
          ?>{
              name: '<?php echo $th->tahun_kunjungan ?>',
              data: [<?php echo $th->hitung ?>]

          }, 
          <?php }?>
          ]
      });
  });
  </script>
  ```

Thank's :)

Comment: Why does it not work? That linked question has a good solution.

Comment: i don't know
implement to my code please help me..

Comment: If you have four charts on the page, then why do you need themes? I suggest to simply set all required option in the chart. Just the way you set any other options (like `series`).

Comment: My client want different from other design chart

Comment: Yes, of course, but that's not wha I meant. I want to say you don't need to use`setOptions` method. You can pass all options when creating chart.

Comment: Can you give me example code, i confused :(